# "Couldn't forward the HTTP response back to the HTTP client: It seems the user clicked on the 'Stop' button in his browser."

Tags: nginx, passenger, mongomapper, padrino

Take a look at the code [on GitHub](http://github.com/eturk/fhsclock).

What's happening is I try to create a Schedule (one of the models) and it is suddenly failing to do anything. Using the built-in Padrino server, it is not outputting any errors. However, with Passenger, I am getting this.

```
[36m  DEBUG[0m - [[33m22/Aug/2011 13:52:13[0m] "GET (0.3754ms) 127.0.0.1 - - /admin/schedules  - 200 3606"
[ pid=3939 thr=3067513712 file=ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:921 time=2011-08-22 13:52:13.968 ]: Couldn't forward the HTTP response back to the HTTP client: It seems the user clicked on the 'Stop' button in his browser.
[36m  DEBUG[0m - [[33m22/Aug/2011 13:52:13[0m] "GET (0.3211ms) 127.0.0.1 - - /admin/schedules  - 200 3606"
[36m  DEBUG[0m - [[33m22/Aug/2011 13:52:19[0m] "POST (0.0493ms) 127.0.0.1 - - /admin/schedules/create  - 302 -"
[36m  DEBUG[0m - [[33m22/Aug/2011 13:52:19[0m] "Resolving layout /var/www/fhsclock/admin/views/layouts/application"
[36m  DEBUG[0m - [[33m22/Aug/2011 13:52:19[0m] "GET (0.0384ms) 127.0.0.1 - - /admin/schedules  - 200 3606"
```

I think the second line is the problem (I'm not clicking Stop, by the way). This is the only place this is happening--when creating a new entry of another model, it works fine.

What is causing this?

Comment: I was never able to resolve this issue, I just switched to using Unicorn.